# Use protocol that inherits from another protocol as an associated type

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

I am trying to make a protocol that has has two associated types. One of these associated types is for a delegate. When I try to use another protocol as the associated type, I get the error "Type 'HostConnectionService' does not conform to protocol 'ConnectionService'". The code I have is written below:

```
protocol ConnectionService: class {
    associatedtype Peer: Sharelist.Peer
    associatedtype Delegate: ConnectionServiceDelegate
    var connectedPeers: [Peer] { get }
    var delegate: Delegate? { get }
}

protocol ConnectionServiceDelegate { }

// Error
class HostConnectionService: NSObject, ConnectionService {
    typealias Peer = GuestPeer
    typealias Delegate = HostConnectionServiceDelegate

    var delegate: HostConnectionServiceDelegate?
    var connectedPeers: [GuestPeer] = []
}

protocol HostConnectionServiceDelegate: ConnectionServiceDelegate { }
```

When I change the line

```
typealias Delegate = HostConnectionServiceDelegate
```

to be of a non-protocol type, I no longer get an error:

```
struct NonProtocolConnectionServiceDelegate: ConnectionServiceDelegate { }

// No Error
class HostConnectionSertice: NSObject, ConnectionService {
    ...
    typealias Delegate = NonProtocolConnectionServiceDelegate
    ...
}
```

Is this a fundamental Swift limitation, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is too complicated to understand. I tried to simplify it.

It compiles without errors:

```
protocol ProtocolA {}

protocol ProtocolB {
    associatedtype SomeType
}

class SomeClass: ProtocolB {
    typealias SomeType = ProtocolA
}

let object = SomeClass()
```

But the following example is no longer compiled:

```
protocol ProtocolA {}

protocol ProtocolB {
    associatedtype SomeType: ProtocolA
}

class SomeClass: ProtocolB {
    typealias SomeType = ProtocolA
}
```

The error is as follows:

> error: type 'SomeClass' does not conform to protocol 'ProtocolB'
>
> note: possibly intended match 'SomeType' (aka 'ProtocolA') does not conform to 'ProtocolA'

This is because [protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself)

Most likely in your case it is necessary to make the class template:

```
protocol ProtocolA {}

protocol ProtocolB {
    associatedtype SomeType: ProtocolA
}

class SomeClass<T: ProtocolA>: ProtocolB {
    typealias SomeType = T
}

extension Int: ProtocolA {}
extension Double: ProtocolA {}

let object1 = SomeClass<Int>()
let object2 = SomeClass<Double>()
```